# Cognos report studio filter on available options from value prompt

Tags: report, filtering, cognos, cognos-10

I have a few value prompts that don't quite cascade, but they are related. As an example:

- Prompt 1: Manager
- Prompt 2: Shift Supervisor
- Prompt 3: Employee

So if you chose Jim in prompt 1, prompt 2 would be populated by only shift supervisors that Jim is in charge, and so on down the line of value prompts. For the actual report the only prompt that truly matters is the final prompt for employees, the rest just filter down the list of relevant employees.

The problem I'm running into is that all the prompts are optional depending on narrow you want the scope to be, and the query it's looking at is really only looking at the final prompt value. If the final one isn't filled in, but let's say the shift manager is, how can I make the report only show employees under the shift supervisor I've chosen?

To say it another way, if the hierarchy tree looks like this:

- Jim

  - Teri

    - Dave
    - Bill
  - Jon

    - Amanda
    - Joel

where each level represents a different value prompt, if I've chosen Jim as the Manager, and Teri as the shift supervisor, my report is currently showing results for Dave, Bill, Amanda, AND Joel, but I only want to see Dave and Bill.

I have the value prompts filtering appropriately, so how can I make my report see the available options in the final prompt if none are explicitly chosen, instead of not filtering on employees at all?

Answer (score 1):

Generally this is achieved by adding a static value to all your prompts called "All". If you choose "All" in your final prompt, then you add some logic to your where clause to recognise this. For example:

```
([ManagerID] = ?pManagerID? OR ?pManagerID?='All')
AND
([SupervisorID] = ?SupervisorID? OR ?SupervisorID?='All')
AND
([EmployeeID] = ?EmployeeID? OR ?EmployeeID?='All')
```

Then all that remains is all the fiddling about with prompt macros etc. to make your prompts optional as required.

For example if you pick a specific Manager and a specific Supervisor then pick "All" in the employee prompt, this is the result:

```
([ManagerID] = '050' OR ?pManagerID?='All')
AND
([SupervisorID] = '012' OR ?SupervisorID?='All')
AND
([EmployeeID] = 'All' OR ?EmployeeID?='All')
```

Simplified this means:

```
([ManagerID] = '050')
AND
([SupervisorID] = '012')
```

So it won't pick all employees - it will only pick records with your selected ManagerID and SupervisorID

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to get ALL the employees, just the ones that show up in the filtered prompt. If I use an "all" option I'll be getting all the Employees, in the database, not just the two that have already been filtered down.

Comment: Did you try it? I will add more explanation

Comment: Now that two people have suggested something identical, you should probably go try it

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem because I don't need all the employees, I need the employees that are available to choose in the value prompt, which is a subset of employees filtered by the previous value prompt.

Comment: It doesn't return all employees. In the example above it only returns employees that are underneath Supervisor '012'

Comment: True. Though the problem has changed, another hierarchy level was added which through a wrench in the whole thing. I ended up changing the table schema then using all the value prompts to filter instead of just the employees filter.

Comment: Well you might want to take the time to understand this pattern anyway - it's used a lot

Comment: You should reverse the order in your OR clauses. The way you have it, the data source value will always be checked, even if 'All' is passed in. If you put the check for 'All' first, it will only do a comparison at the database level when the value passed in is not 'All'.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I didn't think Cognos was smart enough to short circuit

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the way ORs work to construct a solution. Since only one clause is required for an OR logic construct to return true, you can use this behavior to test from specific to general and stop when at the appropriate level.

```
([EmployeeID] is not missing AND [EmployeeID] = ?EmployeeID?)
OR
([SupervisorID] is not missing AND [SupervisorID] = ?SupervisorID?)
OR
([ManagerID] is not missing AND [ManagerID] = ?ManagerID?)
```

If an employee is selected, the first clause in the OR is used and the specific employee is filtered.

If no employee is selected but a supervisor is, then the first clause will return false and the second clause will be used.

If no employee and no supervisor are selected but the manager is, then the first and second clauses will return false and last clause  will be used.

Comment: So this is used as a filter on the main query?

Comment: Yes. This would be one filter on the main query. You can mark the filter itself as 'optional'.

Comment: I tried this but I was still getting more results than I was expecting.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What results are you getting that you don't expect for a given set of prompts?